# non recursive check of variable length string content

Tags: c++, memcmp

I have a function which takes a char* of variable length and the length.
I want to check if its contents are all white spaces.

It being a variable length, means I cant use a memcmp because I dont know how long to make the second parameter.

Any thoughts on a neat way to check it with out iterating over each character of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonably efficient way to answer this exact requirement is:

```
bool is_whitespace(const char* p, size_t n)
{
    while (n--)
        if (!isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*p++)))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

More generally, it's a good idea to try to store such data in `std::string` variables, which makes solutions like Konrad's `find_first_not_of` more efficient and convenient.

*Thanks to Steve for the comment re isspace on some platforms with non-ASCII string content... e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245348.aspx.

Comment: Cast `char` to an unsigned type before using the `::isspace` function.

Answer (score 4):

Just walk over the chars and check for whitespace (e.g. using the [`isspace`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isspace.html) function).

Alternatively, convert the `char*` to a `std::string` and use string functions, i.e. [`find_first_not_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/). For example, using the “conventional” whitespace characters in pre-Unicode encodings:

```
bool is_all_spaces(char const* text, unsigned len) {
    string str(text, len);
    return str.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n\v\f") == string::npos;
}
```

A more fancy whitespace recognition would cope with arbitrary text encodings / locales. For that reason, using `isspace` is probably superior to the `find_first_not_of` approach.

In either case, using `memcmp` in C++ is ill-advised anyway and you should generally prefer C++ strings to C-style char arrays.

Comment: @Martin Depending on the locale, yes. I should have made it clear that this is only a proof of concept.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if a certain character in a string is of a certain value, and you want to know that for all characters in the string, you *need* to iterate over the string. No way around that. Even `memcmp` loops over the string, it's just hidden from you.
**Edit:** Thought I'd provide a simple implementation for variable length strings:

```
bool is_only_space(const char* str){
  while(*str != '\0'){
    if(*str != ' ')
      return false;
    ++str;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Of course, this only works for null-terminated strings, but that should be a given.

Comment: @matt: Added a simple example for variable-length strings.